# Visual Studio keeps changing references to resources

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a strange problem with Visual Studio. I have a large application in C# with lots of forms and also a `.resx` file that contains strings. I have various language versions of the `.resx` file, e.g.

`MyApplication.resx`, 
`MyApplication.ja.resx`

Now take this piece of code, which refers to a windows control (a label) is contained within the control definition part of the code:

```
this.uxMyLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
resources.ApplyResources(this.uxMyLabel, "uxMyLabel");
this.uxMyLabel.Name = "uxMyLabel";
this.uxMyLabel.ReadOnly = true;
this.uxMyLabel.Text = global::MyNamespace.MyApplication.MY_TEXT_STRING;
```

Every now and again I will build my application only to find that that last line has changed to

```
this.uxMyLabel.Text = global::MyNamespace.MyApplication_ja.MY_TEXT_STRING;
```

Since there is no file called `MyApplication_ja.resx` then of course the build fails and I have to edit and change it back to `MyApplication`

I am not sure when this change happens (while I'm editing the code? While I'm building it?) but it only happens occasionally and to lots of different controls, often a whole file at a time. (though never to the entire project)

I am editing the file in question elsewhere, though not anything to do with that particular control.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Do *not* edit code that's generated by the designer.  Any changes you make will be lost whenever you make a trivial change to the design.  With an unpredictable outcome if the designer code parser actually can make hay of your change.  That statement belongs in the constructor after the InitializeComponent() call.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't have much choice... The application will not build if I don't

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Not really sure how that's relevant. I am asking about the problem/symptom I'm observing and asking why it might be happening.

Comment: You found a hack for "will not build".  One that causes another problem, now it still doesn't build.  So the hack wasn't a solution at all.  The only real solution is to solve the original "will not build" problem.  Nobody can guess what that might take if you don't tell us.

Comment: I never said it was a solution, it was a workaround to get around the original problem, which is what I was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully aware about the configurations at your end, therefor I'm feeling a little constraint in analyzing why VS is having an affinity for **Japanese("ja")** localisation assembly.

But I do see an issue with the way your Form/UserControl is localized, so I'll point it out. And I think sticking to the correct pattern may help getting rid of the mentioned behavior.

The controls should not pick values from global resource like  `this.uxMyLabel.Text = global::MyNamespace.MyApplication.MY_TEXT_STRING;`
instead **Localizable** property of the Form/UserControl must be set to true.
This will create a .resx file exclusively for the Form/Usercontrol and will take out all culture specific properties (of all controls) from the designer to the resx .

This will enable the developer (or designer) to set localised texts for different languages at design time. here is a link  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.100).aspx#

Understanding that you are working on massive application with many forms, my suggestion may be a bit too time consuming nbecause it will involve localizing each control again for all language. 
But incase the problem you mentioned become a pain, perhaps you can give it a try on the most notorious forms(user controls) first.

Hope it helps.